# How to insert a new object into array using LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

I have an array of objects of type A:

```
A[] ar
```

How can I insert a new object `a` into the array **at index i** using LINQ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Linq is for querying, not modifying. Also, if you have the "index `i`" and it falls withing the bounds of the array, you can simply do `ar[i] = a`

Comment: @haim770 SQL is also for querying but you can make insert and delete, so may be also in LINQ it's possible? I don't want to replace, I want to insert a new object.

Comment: What about the existing object at that index?

Comment: @Magnus https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A `List<T>` is not an array as in your question, but if it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

Did the insert using `List<>.Insert()`.